# Django Unit test for models

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models

Below is a class in models.py.

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean(self):
        if self.end and self.start and self.end <= self.start:
            raise ValidationError({
                'end': _('End date should be after start date')
            })

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('decentmark:unit_view', kwargs={'unit_id': self.pk})
```

I have written tests for validating date, length of the string etc. Following are tests for the above class.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from decentmark.models import *



class UnitModelTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Unit.objects.create(name='Python', start='2018-10-25 14:30:59', 
                            end='2017-10-25 14:30:59', description='111',
                            deleted='False')

    def test_name_label(self):
        unit = Unit.objects.get(id=1)  # type: Unit
        field_label = unit._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
        self.assertEquals(field_label, 'name')

    def test_name_max_length(self):
        unit = Unit.objects.get(id=1)
        max_length = unit._meta.get_field('name').max_length
        self.assertEquals(max_length, 200)

    def test_str(self):
        unit = Unit.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_object_name = unit.name
        self.assertEquals(expected_object_name, str(unit))

    def test_date(self):
        unit = Unit.objects.get(id=1)
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            unit.full_clean()
```

Are there any other tests that I need to write for above class in models.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Coverage.py` to check which parts of the code are executed therefore to test those parts.

[Django Documentation about Coverage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#integration-with-coverage-py)